# How to animate an element when the window uses scrollTop

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, animation, jquery-animate

http://boy-coy.com - > this is the perfect animate on an element that i want when site is scrolling down.

I can't create this effect.

Setting the top value of scroll with animate is breaking the site:

```
$('div').animate({
    top : ((div_top)-$(this).scrollTop())
},{queue:false, duration: 900})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Fsx7L/

This is my example using animate. When page is scrolling, animation has a "hard stop", it's not smooth

In boy-coy.com effect,it is 100 times better then mine.

Any ideas?

(sorry for my english)

Comment: I smell [parallax scrolling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallax_scrolling) but I don't know too much about it.

Comment: @13ruce1337 yest, i know that. But i don't care about parallax, only about smooth animate top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i think, that i got it !

```
$(window).bind("scroll",function(){
    old_scroll_div = $('div').css("top").replace(/[^-\d\.]/g, '');
    new_scroll_div = div_top-$(this).scrollTop();    
    $('div').animate({
        top : Math.floor(new_scroll_div)
    },{duration : 1500, queue : false, easing : 'easeOutSine'});
})
```

check out:
http://jsfiddle.net/Fsx7L/4/

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend using .animate() for this

http://jsfiddle.net/Fsx7L/1/

```
.css();
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I want to received smooth animation effect like in http://boy-coy.com

Comment: I ghink the animation is the same, just with smaller steps. With a scrollwheel Plugin you can change the default value of pixel beeing scrollen while using the mousewheel, so you have to scroll more, but also the ankmation is more smooth. And i think it just looks better in that website because there are so many elements beeing repositioned